# Record Video using a for loop

Tags: python, video, raspicam

I am using RPi 2 Model B with a RPi camera module. I'm coding on Python and need to record a video while operating a motor. The code I'm working with looks something like this

```
with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
    camera.start_recording('test.h264')
    for i in range(0,2001):
        *Code to run the motor*
    camera.stop_recording()
```

I'm not sure where to place the `camera.wait_recording()`command. I need the code to start recording, run the motor and then end recording.

Edit:
Ok, what seems to be working is the following code

```
with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
camera.start_recording('test.h264')
for i in range(0,2001):
    *Code to run the motor*
     camera.wait_recording()
camera.stop_recording()
```

So, basically added the `camera.wait_recording()` command in the `for` loop. Though I'm not sure if the recording begins exactly when the `for` loop starts and ends exactly when the `for` loop ends. Also not sure if this is achieving the desired result. 
If somebody could shed some light on this I'd be thankful.

Comment: depends on what the loop does. If you want to record while the loop is running, place the line above the for-loop.

Comment: @576i- yes I do want to record while the loop is running. But what argument do I enter into the wait command or do I leave it blank?

Comment: Because it says [here](http://picamera.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api_camera.html#picamera.camera.PiCamera.wait_recording) that the `camera.wait_recording()` command immediately returns if there is nothing passed, right?

Answer (score 1):

> Though I'm not sure if the recording begins exactly when the for loop starts

The recording starts when you call `start_recording()`.  The docs are pretty explicit about that.

> and ends exactly when the for loop ends

The recording stops when you call `stop_recording()`, *or when something goes wrong*.

The purpose of `wait_recording()` is to check that the recording process hasn't stopped due to error, which will otherwise go unnoticed until you call `stop_recording()`.   It apparently will throw an exception.  That being the case, you probably want to wrap it properly:

```
try:
    camera.wait_recording()
except Exception:
    # Deal with it.
```

There's a bit of discussion in the comments below about exactly which forms of `Exception` that might be.

Comment: Spot on! As to what exception might be thrown - it largely depends on what you're writing to (IOError if it's a file, SocketError if it's a network socket, etc). Basically `wait_recording` is just a sync method to transfer an exception from the background recording thread to the calling thread. If nothing's gone wrong then it's just a wait-state on an event.

Comment: @DaveJones Do you know for a fact those exceptions can be thrown here?   The docs for that leave it up to the imagination, but when I clicked through to [the source](http://picamera.readthedocs.org/en/latest/_modules/picamera/camera.html#PiCamera.wait_recording) I notice the call is really a `try/except` which then throws `PiCameraNotRecording` -- but looking at it again now I realized the meat of the call is probably the subsequent `emitter.wait()` which could throw anything (I'm actually not a python user and did not go further; `try/except/else` is a strange looking sequence to me)....

Comment: ...So I've changed it to the most general case above but if you are sure which ones can come from lower down I'll add that into the answer.

Comment: The PiCameraNotRecording exception is thrown if you call wait_recording on a splitter port which isn't active (so it's a boring case basically). The more important cases are thrown by [encoder.wait](http://picamera.readthedocs.org/en/latest/_modules/picamera/encoders.html#PiEncoder.wait); this simply grabs any exception stored by the [callback](http://picamera.readthedocs.org/en/latest/_modules/picamera/encoders.html#PiEncoder._callback) and raises it (in the main thread because that's where it's being called from)

Comment: I should add that as soon as the encoder callback encounters an exception it stores it (for later raising by `wait`) and then terminates the recording. So, yeah, it can be just about any exception at all depending on the output (and the output can be "anything with a `write()` method", so the scope is pretty wide :)